# Temporary DataFrame subset modification inside a function

Tags: python, pandas

My quesion is *not* about how to deal with `SettingWithCopyWarning`. It is how to *best* deal with it in a specific context.

I have a function to which an entire DataFrame is passed. As part of this function, I'll keep just a subset, then will modify one column, before returning the final results. As expected, this triggers the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

My point is... yes, that's the whole point: I want to work on chunks of my DataFrame without actually touching the source (thus modifying a copy), while clearing memory after each chunk is being processed (hence the function). Here's an illustration:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: def add_one(df, column):
   ...:     df = df[df['A']==1]
   ...:     df['A'] = df['A'] + 1
   ...:     print(df['A'])
   ...:     

In [3]: test_df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2]})

In [4]: add_one(test_df, 'A')
0    2
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
/tmp/ipykernel_132006/2423483857.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['A'] = df['A'] + 1

In [5]: test_df
Out[5]: 
   A
0  1
1  1
2  2
```

Should I just supporess the warning with `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)` (which I understand is bad practice), or is there a smarter way?

Comment: `df = df[df['A']==1].copy()` will fix it as it explicitly forces the creation of a new object which won't have issues being altered in the next line

Comment: OK, thanks. Unfortunately, someone incorrectly marked my question as a duplicate, so thank you for answering first!

Comment: I know this question has since been answered, but I would discourage suppressing warnings in general because even if in this case you understand the warning and it doesn't apply -- if somewhere else in the program the SettingWithCopyWarning warning is merited, it won't be brought to your attention

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. Explicitly calling `copy()` worked.